# Can anyone explain about MongoDB wired tiger lock level?

Tags: mongodb, locking

I've heard wired tiger uses document level lock. But I can't find any details.

In the [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-locks-are-taken-by-some-common-client-operations-), There are only database, collection lock level.

Insert, Remove, Update: database IX locked, collection IX locked.

1. In wired tiger, is it just locking only the related document when inserting, removing, updating?
2. what about transaction? if a transaction uses 2 collection and update 2 documents (1 in each collection), then it just locks only these 2 documents? without locking any collection?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested transactions with same document and other document in same collection.

If there are 2 transactions that writing same document at a time, then second transaction will get WriteConflict error. but in mongodb drive(nodejs), this error has TransientTransactionError label and will be retried during timeout(120 seconds) if you are using transaction by withTransaction.

And If there are 2 transaction that writing different document at a time, then all transactions will go success. so the lock is working in document level.